# Closure of $l_p$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

How can I find closure of $l_p$ in $l_\infty$? I was trying to show that the closure is the whole space but I have failed. What's more now I think that it's not true. I have no idea how to start doing this :( If you can please write some hints.

Comment: Look at step functions in both.

Comment: Do you mean $x_1=(1,0,0,...)$, $x_2=(0,1,0,0,...)$ and so on?

Comment: Thanks. However I don't see how I can aplly this. I was trying to show that in every ball $B(x,r)$ where $x \in l_\infty$ we can find a step function (multiplied by a scalar) it would mean that $cl (l_p) =l_\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose the following facts

1. $c_{00}\subset \ell_p$
2. $\ell_p\subset c_0$
3. $\operatorname{cl}_{\ell_\infty}(c_{00})=c_0$

Comment: Ok, so the proof is something like that:
First and second points are obvious. We will show third. Let $y \notin c_0$, then $\exists_\epsilon \forall _N \exists _{n \ge N} |y_n| > \epsilon$. So we have $||x-y||_{l_\infty}=\sup _n |x_n-y_n|>\epsilon$ for all $x \in c_0$ and it means that $y$ cannot be a limit of points from $c_0$, so we are done. Now we have use simple fact that if  $X \subset Y \subset Z = \operatorname{cl} (Z)$ and $\operatorname{cl}(x)=Z$ then $\operatorname{cl}(Y)=Z$. Is it acceptable? :)

Comment: Yes this is correct.